# Identity function in Scheme

Tags: scheme, identity

Is the identity function pre-defined in Scheme?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, but it's called [`values`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html).  Actually, that's usually used for multiple values, so it's a generalized multiple-arity identity function.

Answer (score 4):

In DrRacket I know that `identity` works. For example, `(identity 12) => 12`

Comment: link to the documentation: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=identity#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._identity%29%29