# In Scheme, how do you do probability?

Tags: random, scheme, probability

If i have a procedure like sub1 and a list, how do apply a probability value to each element of the list?

Something like this: `(blahblah sub1 '(1 1 1 1) 0.5)`

I want it to apply sub1 to each element with a probability of, for example, 0.5. But, I'm not sure how to do it. I think I have to use random some how but I'm not sure how. Help?

This is what i have so far. It doesn't work at all.

```
(define map-random
  (lambda (proc ls p)
    (map
      (lambda (x)
        (if (null? ls) '()
            (proc x (+ x (random p))))) ls)))
```

Comment: So what you're saying is, you want to [`map`](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Mapping-of-Lists.html) a sequence with a function acts as *either* "sub1" or the [identity function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969927/identity-function-in-scheme) based on a [random value](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Random-Numbers.html)? That is, consider a function that takes in x and returns *either* sub1(x) or x depending upon a random value.

Comment: Yep. that's want I to do.

Comment: Then do it - it will either work or won't work. But even if it doesn't work, posting the code attempted and how it "doesn't work" will result in a better basis for the question.

Comment: Consider this: "if random in range [0, 1) < p then return proc(x) else return x"

Comment: well, its returning like decimal numbers which isn't right. If the proc is add 1 and the list is full of zeros, then it should be returning 1's and 0's, right?

Comment: Ok, i think i got it. It seems to work.

(define map-random
    (lambda (proc ls p)
      (map
        (lambda (x)
          (if (null? ls) '()
              (if (< p (random 2)) (proc x)
                  x))) ls)))

Comment: There is still too much work with the `null?` stuff, but it's closer .. note `(random 2)` (returns 0 or 1) is not the same as `(random)` (returns value in `[0, 1)`) so that comparison will yield interesting results. Also note that `(< p r)` and `(< r p)` yield two different tests - only one is correct here.

Comment: What do you mean when you say there's too much work with the null? But, when I only put random, I get an argument count error

Comment: I mean it's not the job of the function passed to `map` to deal with container management - it's only to map a new value from a provided value. Check with your implementation of Scheme for the appropriate `random` documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to write something like this:

```
(define map-random
  (lambda (proc ls p)
    (map (lambda (e)
           (if (<= (random) p)
               (proc e)
               e))
         ls)))
```

Notice that `map` takes care of traversing the input list and building the output list, you only have to take care of deciding what to do with each element - and in this case, that means whether to apply the given procedure to an element or to leave the element alone depending on a random value - if the value is within a given probability apply the procedure, if not use the same element. It works as expected:

```
(map-random sub1 '(1 1 1 1) 0.5)
=> '(1 1 0 1) ; a possible output
```